# TableLayout vs LinearLayout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to get the right layouts for a screen I am building:
[image]

Basically from what I have read, it seems that the best approach would be to split the screen in two using a TableLayout and within each place a LinearLayout.

I've tried to get something done, but given that I have no background on Xamarin development things are a bit more tricky, I'm mainly a BE developer.

Answer (score 2):

> Basically from what I have read, it seems that the best approach would be to split the screen in two using a TableLayout and within each place a LinearLayout.

It is not a must to use a `TableLayout`. You can also use a `LinearLayout` as the base panel and two `LinearLayout`s as sub panels:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--You contents here-->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--You contents here-->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Notes: the tricky thing is by setting the sub `LinearLayout`s' `layout_width` to `0dp` and `layout_weight` to 1 to let them share a ratio of width by 1:1.